# Confirm that mysqli extension is not installed

Tags: mysql, php, logging, php5

Recently I discovered that mysqli extension is not installed in my server <strike>Centos version 2.6</strike>. I confirm it because I change the driver of db connection from `mysqli` to `mysql` and now works fine. So, is there another way/log  to determinate this problem? because the apache error_log does not say anything about it.

This really is not a problem, but it could be more complex in future. Why? because using the mysqli driver, the website die with a blank page with no errors/warnings to help me to troubleshooting it. I don't like the idea of discover the problems with magics arts or testing line per line. Should be some log file that help me to debug it.

In order provide information to help on this issue, I did:

```
 cat /proc/version 
 Linux version 2.6.18-308.el5.028stab099.3 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46))
```

Comment: What is the problem then? You know `mysqli` isn't installed and setting it to `mysql` seemed to solve your problem. Also, are you sure you're using CentOS version **2.6**?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen, I have updated the post :)

Comment: So you want to use the `mysqli` driver in you PHP application? Did you try to `yum install php-mysqli`? Or, if you wanna check if it's installed, do a simple `rpm -q php-mysqli`.

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen, sorry for my poor explanation: it's not my native lang. I know how to install mysqli. Suppose that you don't know why your page is totally in white, exist any log file where I could see errors like `[november 2, 2012] php doesn't know what mysqli is in  index.php` ??. With this error I can figure out that there is something wrong with `mysqli` and then I (or my partners) can fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost here. If your PHP application fails, the PHP code should include error messages. How to do this properly is explained in http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php .

Comment: Exactly, now you got it! But using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` doesn't print nothing. That's is the reason why I'm trying to catch the error in some log file unknown for me.

Comment: So you need to know if `mysql` or `mysqli` is available from PHP? Try something like `if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) { // mysqli not available}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can confirm that `mysqli` is installed, or not, by listing the installed modules. SSH into your Cent OS box, and issue the following command.

```bash
php -m | grep mysqli
```

If nothing is returned, then you do not have `mysqli.so` loaded. Check if you have the shared object is installed on you system.

```bash
# Located extension dir
php -i | grep extension_dir
# List mysql.so in the path returned from the previous command
ls -la /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so
```

If the mysqli.so is present, and has the permissions `-rwxr-x-rx`, you'll need to load/enable the mysqli extension in the systems global `php.ini` file.

```bash
# Adjust path to correct php.ini file. 
# Run `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` to locate, if needed
# It might be easier to use vi, or nano, for this
sudo echo "extension=mysqli.so" >> /etc/php5/php.ini
# Restart apache
sudo service httpd restart
```

Else. If you do not have `mysqli.so` present in your system. You can install the rpm by following your systems package manager, and repeating the previous php.ini step.

```bash
sudo yum install php5-mysqli
```

Comment: Windows users might want to refer to [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/1017967/515968)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly `sudo yum install php5-mysqli` this did not install mysqli package for me. More surprisingly, I have PHP Version 5.5.31 and I assumed, it had installed mysqli by default. But I was wrong. I had to install and rebuild apache from WHM.

**To install mysqli using EachApache:**

1. Login to WHM as 'root' user.
2. Either search for "EasyApache" or go to
3. Software > EasyApache Scroll down and select a build option (Previously Saved Config)
4. Click Start "Start customizing based on
   profile"
5. Select the version of Apache and click "Next Step".
6. Select the version of PHP and click "Next Step".
7. Chose additional options within the "Short Options List"
8. Select "Exhaustive Options List" and
   look for "MySQL Improved    extension"
9. Click "Save and Build"

[Source](https://milesweb.com/forums/how-to's/how-to-enable-mysqli-extension-on-cpanelwhm-using-easyapache/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this for all **Windows** users (like me) and to add up to [emcconville](https://serverfault.com/users/133830/emcconville)'s perfect [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/445963/515968):

> You can confirm that mysqli is installed, or not, by listing the installed modules. SSH into your Cent OS box, and issue the following command.

```
php -m | findstr /C:"mysqli"
```

You can use the following command to find, where PHP is installed on you system.

```
where php 
:: Returns C:\PHP\php.exe on my system
:: This yields to extensions being here: C:\PHP\ext
dir C:\PHP\ext | findstr /C:"mysqli"
:: shows weather "php_mysqli.dll" is installed
```

Loading and enabling the extension works [just as in Linux](https://serverfault.com/a/445963/515968) - it also lies at the path found above with `where php`. Notepad does the trick too, but `echo "extension=mysqli.so" >> /etc/php5/php.ini` works too in a command line with sufficient permissions.

If it isn't present, refer to [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#Loading) for loading/installing, especially paragraph  "**Loading an extension**"